Confused by statement of Fisher Information Metric in Paper Using Statistical Manifolds
I've been reading the paper Fisher Information Embedding for Node and Graph Learning by Chen, Pellizzoni and Borgwardt, which uses statistical manifolds. My very limited understanding of statistical manifolds for parametric continuous distributions is:

elements of the manifold are probability density functions (pdfs)
the local homeomorphism is with the Euclidean space of parameters. Thus, coordinates are parameter vectors.
the tangent space is spanned by elements of the Fisher score vector. Thus elements of the tangent space for continuous distributions are functions (in the span of partial derivatives of the log-likelihood).
the Fisher information metric for continuous distributions is an inner product between functions (partial derivatives of the log-likelihood function),

However, in the paper, in equation 6, they define what they claim is the Fisher information metric as
$$
\langle \theta,\theta'\rangle_{g_{\theta_0}}\equiv \theta^\top I(\theta_0)\theta'\qquad\forall \theta,\theta'\in T_{\theta_0}M
$$
where $\theta,\theta'$ are parameters of the distribution, $M$ is the statistical manifold and $T_{\theta_0}M$ is the tangent space to the manifold at $\theta_0\in M$. However, I have some questions:

Shouldn't elements of the tangent space for a statistical manifold of continuous distributions be functions, and not coordinates in parameter space?
Isn't the Fisher information metric an inner product between partial derivatives of the log-likelihood function, not an inner product between parameter vectors?

Is there something wrong in my understanding? Or is their inner product not between elements of the tangent space?

I think one of the $\theta$'s on the right hand side of your equation should be $\theta'$.

You write "where $\theta,\theta'$ are parameters of the distribution", but you also write "$\theta,\theta'\in T_{\theta_0}M$", which contradicts that. Does the paper make both claims as well?

@N.Virgo you are right, thanks. Fixed.

@N.Virgo Yes it does. That's my question: shouldn't elements of the tangent space be functions in the span of the log-likelihood partial derivatives, not parameters?

Hmm, well the paper says $T_{\theta_0}\mathcal{M} = \Theta$ (equation 6), which I guess they would justify because they are both (ismorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'd say it's a bit lazy to identify them because they're conceptually different, but that's probably what they're doing. I'd have to read the paper in more detail to be sure though, which I don't think I have time to do.

Ok, thank you. So you're confirming that the tangent space is not equal to the space of parameters. I suspected as much, but I am very new to differential/information geometry so wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. After they do that, they don't do much more information geometry, so it isn't really important to read the paper. Thank you again!
